# 'PosixPath' object is not subscriptable[GeoDjango BUG]

Tags: python, django, geodjango

Using `ogrinfo -so` I've found the structure of the shapefile and based on this structure I've created a model:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Villages(models.Model):
.
.
.
```

After that I've created the `load.py` [as mentioned here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#layermapping) inside the same directory of `models.py`:

[image]

```
from pathlib import Path
from django.contrib.gis.utils import LayerMapping
from .models import Villages

villages_mapping = {
.
.
.
}

villages = Path(__file__).resolve().parent / 'gis' / 'villages.shp'

def run(verbose=True):
    lm = LayerMapping(Villages, villages, villages_mapping, transform=False)
    lm.save(strict=True, verbose=verbose)
```

Then, I try to use `load.py`:

`python3 manage.py shell` > `from geodata import load` > `load.run()`

But I see this strange error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<console>", line 1, in
<module>   File
"/home/maxdragonheart/DEV_FOLDER/Django/Enographiae/enographiae_dev/enographiae/geodata/load.py", line 32, in run
    lm = LayerMapping(Villages, villages, villages_mapping, transform=False)   File
"/home/maxdragonheart/DEV_FOLDER/Django/Enographiae/enographiae_dev/devenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/utils/layermapping.py", line 99, in __init__
    self.layer = self.ds[layer] TypeError: 'PosixPath' object is not subscriptable
```

**EDIT**:

Maybe the problem is inside `layermapping.py`. I've replicated the tutorial using the original code and datas and I see this:

```
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/maxdragonheart/DEV_FOLDER/Django/Singole APP/GeoDjango/webgis/tutorialgeodjango/load.py", line 23, in run
    lm = LayerMapping(WorldBorder, world_shp, world_mapping, transform=False)
  File "/home/maxdragonheart/DEV_FOLDER/Django/Singole APP/GeoDjango/devenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/utils/layermapping.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.layer = self.ds[layer]
TypeError: 'PosixPath' object is not subscriptable
```

**EDIT 2**:

Using the code from [Django 2.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#layermapping) I've no problem to upload datas. How I can report this bug?

**EDIT 3**:

The problem is also in Django 3.1.3

Comment: what is PosixPath and where did you used it?

Comment: This is the problem. I don't know what is `PosixPath`. I've simple copied and pasted the code from the official guide

Comment: I think all you need to do is convert path to string, because you're using `Path` and Django expects either path as `str` or `DataSource` instance. Change `villages` to `str(villages)` and let's hope that's it :)

Comment: If you add this as answer I can vote you @Borut

Comment: Thanks. I added the answer with full explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django documentation  for [LayerMapping API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/layermapping/#layermapping-api) is not 100 % clear on a data type for path, but if you check the source code, you'll see it expects either a string or DataSource instance.

Below is the relevant code from the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e46ca51c249677c52e04db28fc0c60ae1948b3b2/django/contrib/gis/utils/layermapping.py#L85).

```
def __init__(self, model, data, mapping, layer=0,
             source_srs=None, encoding='utf-8',
             transaction_mode='commit_on_success',
             transform=True, unique=None, using=None):
    """
    A LayerMapping object is initialized using the given Model (not an instance),
    a DataSource (or string path to an OGR-supported data file), and a mapping
    dictionary.  See the module level docstring for more details and keyword
    argument usage.
    """
    # Getting the DataSource and the associated Layer.
    if isinstance(data, str):
        self.ds = DataSource(data, encoding=encoding)
    else:
        self.ds = data
    self.layer = self.ds[layer]
```

The comment mentions **string path** and later in code there is a check if `data` argument is a string (path in this case) in initializes `DataSource` instance with it.

Simply changing `Path` to `str` will fix your problem.

```
lm = LayerMapping(Villages, str(villages), villages_mapping, transform=False)
```